# HasValidFileNameChars fails for UNC files

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

For me HasValidFileNameChars function (in Delphi XE7) returns false for UNC files:

```
B:= IOUtils.TPath.HasValidFileNameChars('\\ETA-PC\tests\test.ini', FALSE)          
B is false now
```

This means that if you try to validate the filename that I show in my test (yes the file is real and as you can see its name is correct) HasValidFileNameChars will fail. HasValidPathChars work!
Is this normal?

-
Edit:

In the Help page, the first parameter is named 'path'. Which made me believe that the function will accept full paths.

Quote:

```
 Name        Meaning         
 Path        The verified file name string.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HasValidPathChars](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.HasValidPathChars) instead of [HasValidFileNameChars](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.HasValidFileNameChars). A file name cannot contain the backslash.

Answer (score 3):

The function behaves correctly because a `\` is not a valid character for a file name. It is the path separator.

The distinction here is between file names and paths. Using your example, `\\ETA-PC\tests\test.ini` is a path, but the file name is `test.ini`.

I suspect that you are looking for [`HasValidPathChars`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.HasValidPathChars).